# Query Sting in my own MVC Framework

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I have my own little MVC Framework . 
It has its own .htaccess file which redirects URLs to

```
index.php?Load=$1
```

So every time I try to run Query String for Example:

```
http:\\localhost\contact\func?id=56032&post=2
```

It takes just `http:\\localhost\contact\func`

How can I get Query String (id,Post) via  $_GET variable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look to the QSA flag in htaccess files : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

With this flag, parameters on a rewrited url will be preserved. So, with this code :

```
RewriteRule /pages/(.+) /page.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

a request for /pages/123?one=two will be mapped to /page.php?page=123&one=two.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) and [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str):

```
parse_str(parse_url($_GET["Load"], PHP_URL_QUERY), $_GET);
```

Then you can access via a `$_GET["post"];`